# JavaScript no funciona

Tags: javascript, php, html

JavaScript funcionaba bien, se realizaba el envío de AJAX, la consulta... Pero ahora al volverlo a comprobar después de unos días, no funciona, en otra página similar tampoco. El error en la consola es **Uncaught ReferenceError: eliminar is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick**, y no entiendo que ocurre, no he modificado el código. ¿Puede estar relacionado el error con session_start()?, me ponía un error sobre las cabeceras por eso lo he puesto encima del comienzo de JavaScript. Lo único que he estado modificando son las cookies de PHP en el login.

```js
      <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //recibes el idreserva como parámetro
        function eliminar(idreserva) {
            //ejecutas el ajax
            var bool=confirm("¿Eliminar Reserva?");
            if(bool){
                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'eliminareserva.php',
                data: {idreserva},
                success: function (data) { 
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
}
            else{
                alert("No se ha eliminado la Reserva");
            }
            
        }

        }
        function actualizar() {
            //ejecutas el ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'Actualizar Datos.php',
                data: $('#datos').serialize(),
                success: function (data) { 
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
      </script>
```

```html
<body>
      <?php
    session_start();
    //error_reporting(0);
    require_once "Conexión.php";
    $idcliente = $_SESSION["idcliente"];
      ?>
      <h1>Reservas</h1>
             <?php
            //require_once "connection.php";
            
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE idcliente = '$idcliente'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta );                     
            
            ?>
    <p></p>     
    <table borde='2'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Idreserva</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>Nº Personas</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>Nº de Mesa</th>
                <th>Valoración</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
            while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))  
            {
            
            ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['id']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['fecha']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['hora']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['personas']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['importe'].' €' ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idmesa']?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['Valoración']?></td>
                   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="eliminar('<?= $columna['id'] ?>')">Eliminar Reserva</button></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } 
            mysqli_close( $conexion );?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tiene nada que ver PHP con que javascript no funcione. Ya que estas usando Jquery te propongo que tus funciones se aniden dentro de una función general que se conoce como `ready`.

```
<script>
$( () => {

 function eliminar( idreserva ) {
   ...
   //tu lógica aquí
 }

 function actualizar() {
   ...
   // tu lógica aquí
 }

});
</script>
```

Te dejo filosofía de esta implementación [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)